# C# Offreg.dll 'System.AccessViolationException' ORGetValue

Tags: c#, winapi, registry

I am trying to obtain a value from a registry key contained in an offline hive. The code would compile but I am getting 'System.AccessViolationException' or the program just closes.

I think the program is trying to read of write to memory that is not allocated. However I have tried to allocate memory for myValue using stringbuilder.

When i set pcbData to any value lower than 66 i get a return value of 234, which means that the specified buffer size is not large enough to hold the data.

OROpenHive seems be working as I am getting a return value of 0.

Syntax for ORGetValue at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210767(v=vs.85).aspx

```
DWORD ORGetValue(
    _In_         ORHKEY Handle,
    _In_opt_     PCWSTR lpSubKey,
    _In_opt_     PCWSTR lpValue,
    _Out_opt_    PDWORD pdwType,
    _Out_opt_    PVOID pvData,
    _Inout_opt_  PDWORD pcbData
);
```

Here is my code:

```
    [DllImport("offreg.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "ORGetValue",          SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern uint ORGetValue(
        IntPtr Handle, 
        string lpSubKey, 
        string lpValue, 
        out uint pdwType, 
        out StringBuilder pvData, 
        ref uint pcbData);

    [DllImport("offreg.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern uint OROpenHive(
        String lpHivePath,
        out IntPtr phkResult);

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr myHive;
        String filepath = @"C:\Users\JON\Desktop\NTUSER.DAT";

        StringBuilder myValue = new StringBuilder("", 256);
        uint pdwtype;
        uint pcbdata = 66;

        uint ret2 = OROpenHive(filepath, out myHive);
        this.textBox1.Text = ret2.ToString();

        uint ret3 = ORGetValue(myHive, "Environment", "TEMP", out pdwtype, out myValue,  ref pcbdata);
        this.textBox1.Text = ret3.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the result wrong. `pcbdata` should be passed in the size of the buffer, and it will contain the actual number of characters read after the function returns.

Winapi functions don't know what size are the buffers, so even if you are allocating 256 bytes, you are telling `ORGetValue` you have allocated only 66... if you are reading a key which needs more than 66 bytes, it will return `234` (or `ERROR_MORE_DATA`).

You'd typically do something like:

```
StringBuilder myValue = new StringBuilder("", 256);
uint pcbdata = myValue.Capacity;
//...
uint ret3 = ORGetValue(myHive, "Environment", "TEMP", out pdwtype, out myValue,  ref pcbdata);
this.textBox1.Text = "Read " + pcbdata.ToString() + " bytes - returned: " + ret3.ToString();
```

If your key is 66 bytes, then this should read: `Read 66 bytes - returned: 0`

Comment: I must be missing something. Visual Basic does not allow uint pcbdata = myValue.Capacity();

Comment: You are basically allocating 256 bytes for the returned string, but telling the function you have allocated only 66 (so the function thinks your buffer is only 66 bytes long). If it needs more than 66 bytes, it will complain.

Comment: Sorry i messed up with the edit button. What i meant to say was this.  Visual Basic does not allow uint pcbdata = myValue.Capacity();   I keep getting "Non-Invocable member 'System.Text.StringBuilder.Capacity' cannot be used like a method".

Comment: Even when changing the value of pcbdata to 256, I am still getting System.AccessViolationException.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see that: try not to use `out` on the `StringBuilder` parameter... you are not getting a `StringBuilder` on return, you are filling the one you pass in. Remove the `out` both on the definition and on the calling

Comment: Also, it's `Capacity` as a property, not as a calling function (see edit to answer)